# Passing A Data Object Or Parts Of Data Object In Methods?

Tags: c#, class-design

```
public class DataObject{
    public int Value1;
    public int Value2;
    public int Value3;
    public int Value4;
    public int Value5;

    public DataObject(){}
}

public class SomeClass{
    public SomeClass(){}
    public void MultiplyFirstThreeValues(int Value1, int Value2, int Value3){
        return Value1*Value2*Value3;
    }
    public void MultiplyFirstThreeValues(DataObject d){
        return d.Value1*d.Value2*d.Value3;
    }
}
```

Which is a better practice, to send each variable needed to a method or an entire data object (in the case where not every variable in the data object is used)?  This may be an "art more than science" question, but if you can't give a hard and fast rule, then I'd be interested in hearing what would be the motivation to do one over the other (in this case where not all of the data object's values are used in the method).

Thanks, I'm looking forward to learning more about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would opt for option **C** leave the logic within the object itself:

```
  public class DataObject
  {
    private int Value1;
    private int Value2;
    private int Value3;
    private int Value4;
    private int Value5;

    public DataObject(){}

    public int MultiplyFirstThreeValues()
    {
        return Value1*Value2*Value3;
    }
 }
```

**Edit:** 
In response to the comment - I'll add a quote:

> Procedural code gets information then
>   makes decisions. Object-oriented code
>   tells objects to do things.

It's just a better design approach imo since it lets you hide the way you actually get your results / do your implementation. The way you have it currently set up more reflects the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), which can be powerful, but also adds more complexity since the interface to your class has now all these public members. If your calculation would span multiple `DataObject`'s and/or other types this actually might make sense though but I would definitely use encapsulation if I can get away with it.

Comment: I'm looking at my own code, and this approach makes a lot of sense.  I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: You still might need the parameters object to initialize the class.

Comment: Ok, actually, I've given this more thought and this approach is starting to bother me. In my mind (and I certainly could be wrong (I'm a noob)) a data object should be used simply to store data, and any manipulation of that data should take place outside of the data object.  Does that make sense and align with "good coding practices"?

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: if you have more than 7 parameters (though some would say more than 3), consider using an [Introduce parameters object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) refactoring.

In general, if you have a small number of parameters, pass parts of the object, particularly if you don't expect the number of parameters and their types to change.

If the above is not the case (you expect changes in the numbers/types of the parameters and/or you have many of them), use the object.

---

Note:

Having many parameters is a code smell that can indicate that your method/class is doing too much and should be broken up.

Answer (score 1):

A method signature with many input parameters is often said to be an indication that there is a class missing. How many are many? Impossible to say, but three does not strike me as particularly many.

Another thing to put into the thought process is whether the values *always* come from the same object, in the same manner. If it could be that the method could be used for other combinations of input, perhaps keeping a multi-parameter input is better. Of course, if there are really many parameters, you could provide a specially designed type for the parameter set, and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I would favour passing the object only, despite not using all proerties as this leads to smaller method signatures which I feel are easier to mentally parse when code reading than many parameters

Comment: Ok, I'm not bashing your post, just interested in learning more about your position.  When I see my code, I see which values of my data object are being passed to my method, which can be valuable when I'm reading code in that context (makes things easier to understand).  I know this is still mostly personal preference, but do you think it's more important to keep it simple than to keep it more intuitive?

Comment: I guess, the more I think about it, by passing a data object instead of parts of a data object, you force the code reader to see the method him or herself to find out which parts of the data object are used, which now doesn't seem like such a bad thing. Being able to see which parts are used at the method call is a small gain for the clutter added by passing each part of the data object.

Comment: Its a psycology thing. For me, when you hit 3 or more parameters its much harder (IMHO) to scan a source line and remember which parameter does what than a well named object.  Having said that it rather depends on well named classes and parameters.  I think it is a very personal thing.  I would simply say go with whatever YOU find clearer.